# Prompt user to unlock device and then start an activity

Tags: android

I have an android app that can be used to manage tasks. A reminder is shown when it is time to perform a task via an activity. If the phone is locked, the activity is shown on the locked screen. The activity has information about the task and a couple of actions that a user can take. One of the actions that a user can take is to view the task. There is a `View` button which when clicked is supposed to start the app and show the task to the user.

Now when the phone is locked and user taps the `View` button, I want to first prompt the user to unlock the phone and then start the activity. I am having difficulty figuring out how to prompt user to unlock the device. I have tried a couple of things that I found on the internet but they didn't help. I tried the following things:

1. `createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent` but this starts an activity where user can confirm that they know the phone PIN but the device stays locked after the user has entered the password.
2. `newKeyguardLock` but this I found is used to disable the keyguard altogether and not used to prompt the user to enter their PIN
3. `requestDismissKeyguard` - I was not able to use this because this is introduced in API 26 only.

I have seen other apps do that and also when a user clicks on a notification, the user is first prompted to unlock the device and then the app is launched. I want to do something similar. Please let me know how can I achieve it.

Comment: worth noting that although not available until API 26, requestDismissKeyguard does exactly what you require. I've not been able to find anything that achieves the same on older versions of Android.

Comment: I was able to achieve this on older API levels by specifying `activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);` flag on the activity that I am resuming.

Comment: Does this work for secure keyguards? i.e ones with a PIN code?

Comment: Yes, it can be used for secure keyguards.